# Value of $x$ such that the area under the curve of $lnx$ up to $x$ is $1$.

Tags: integration, logarithms, area, wolfram-alpha

This value would be the solution to:$$\int_{0}^{a}\ln(x)dx=1$$
With integration by parts this is well known to be $[x\ln(x)-x]^a_0=1$ or what is the same:$$a\ln(a)-a=1$$ The limit at $0$ easily dismissed as $0$ with L'Hôpital.

Oddly, WolframAlpha outputs $e^{W(1/e)+1}$ as a solution, where $W(z)$ is the product log function. This is aproximately $3.6$. But  if I input $$\int_0^{e^{W(1/e)}+1}\ln(x)dx$$ it doesn't compute. Surely I must have gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't have any problem computing [the last integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+e%5E%281+%2B+ProductLog%281%2Fe%29%29+of+ln%28x%29+dx) using Wolfram.

Comment: (1) Just because there is an asymptote at a lower/upper bound of an interval doesn't always mean the area will be infinite. (2) I don't understand the question. What is $a$?

Comment: @Accelerator So that's where I went wrong. Could you elaborate on this idea? $a$ is a value on the X axis for which the area from 0 until $a$ should be 0, or rather, the area from 1 to $a$ should be equal to the negative of that from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: The function $\ln(x)$ is improperly integrable on $(0,1]$ because $\lim_{a \to 0^+}\int_{a}^{1}\ln(x)dx$ converges. If you want to find such an $a$ such that $\int_{0}^{a}\ln\left(x\right)dx=0$ or $\int_{1}^{a}\ln\left(x\right)dx=0$, all you have to do is evaluate the integral and solve for $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you agree that the following is true: $$\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x} \, dx = 1. \tag{1}$$

After all, we know that the antiderivative of $e^{-x}$ is $-e^{-x}$, hence for any positive real $N$, we have $$\int_{x=0}^N e^{-x} \, dx = \Bigl[-e^{-x}\Bigr]_{x=0}^N = -e^{-N} + e^{-0} = 1 - e^{-N}. \tag{2}$$
Consequently, the improper integral $(1)$ has value $$\lim_{N \to \infty} 1 - e^{-N} = 1 - 0 = 1. \tag{3}.$$

If you view this geometrically, it means that the area under the curve $y = e^{-x}$ on the interval $x \in [0,\infty)$ is $1$.  So by reflection symmetry, it also means that the area under the curve $y = e^x$ on the interval $x \in (-\infty, 0]$ is also $1$.  And then by a further reflection about the line $y = x$, this implies that the absolute area under the curve of $y = \log x$ on the interval $x \in (0, 1]$ is also $1$:  see the diagram below.

[image]

The blue curve is $y = e^x$.  The orange curve is the inverse function, $y = \log x$.  The blue shaded region is has the area $$\int_{x=-\infty}^0 e^x \, dx = 1$$ as demonstrated above.  The orange shaded region, being the reflection of the blue region, also has absolute area $1$; however, as it lies below the $x$-axis, its **signed** area is represented by the integral $$\int_{x=0}^1 \log x \, dx = -1. \tag{4}$$

This in turn implies that the value of $a$ for which $$\int_{x=0}^a \log x \, dx = 1 \tag{5}$$ is the value for which $$\int_{x=1}^a \log x \, dx = 2, \tag{6}$$ since $\log 1 = 0$.  It is not difficult to see that such a value does in fact exist.  We would use integration by parts with the choice $$u = \log x, \quad du = \frac{1}{x} \, dx, \\ dv = dx, \quad v = x, \tag{7}$$  to compute the indefinite integral $$\int \log x \, dx = uv - \int v \, du = x \log x - \int x \cdot \frac{1}{x} \, dx = x \log x - x + C.$$  Hence $$\int_{x=1}^a \log x \, dx = \Bigl[ x \log x - x \Bigr]_{x=1}^a = a \log a - a - (1 \log 1 - 1) = a \log a - a + 1. \tag{8}$$  As we require this to be equal to $2$, we have the equation
$$a (-1 + \log a) = 1, \tag{9}$$ which has no elementary closed form solution but has the approximate numerical solution $a \approx 3.59112$.

Comment: Beautifully written. Thank you! Also, forgive me as I am new here, but how are you including graphs?

Answer (score 2):

Here is
$$
\int_0^a\ln(x)\;dx
$$

[image: graph]

The spot where it crosses the line $y=1$ is, indeed,
$$
e^{W(1/e)+1}=\frac{1}{W(1/e)} \approx 3.5911
$$

This integral is a **convergent** improper integral.  See "improper integral" in the index of your calculus textbook.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote
$$\int_0^a \log(x)\,dx=a (\log (a)-1)$$ Now, suppose that you want that
$$a (\log (a)-1)=b$$ Rewrite first
$$a (\log (a)-1)=e\, \frac a e \,\log \left(\frac{a}{e}\right) $$ Let $t=\frac{a}{e}$ to make $$t\log(t)=\frac be$$ Exponentiate
$$t^t=e^{b/e}=k$$ and look at the definition of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

So
$$t^t=k \quad \implies \quad t=W(k)=e^{W\left(\frac{b}{e}\right)}\quad \implies \quad a=e\,e^{W\left(\frac{b}{e}\right)}=e^{1+W\left(\frac{b}{e}\right)}$$